# xmldocument inserting a string already formatted as xml

Tags: xml, document

I need to insert an XmlNode into an XmlDocument with a string returned from a database.  The sting in the database is already formatted as Xml.  the string from the db also includes characters such as double quotes and < and >.  I have tried XmlDocumnetFragement and adding as innerxml.  Both error because of the special characters.  The data returned by the db looks like this.

```
<ON STMT = "*" COCE = "COMPSTAT EQ 0"/>
SHOUT WHEN = "EXECTIME" MESSAGE = "Job execution exceeds 30 minutes" TIME = ">030" />
```

I need the output to look like this.

```
<some other tag /><SHOUT WHEN = "EXECTIME" MESSAGE = "Job execution exceeds 30 minutes" TIME = ">030" /><another tag>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly figured out the goal of your method, but i recommend you to use XDocument and XElement classes instead of XmlDocument and XmlNode.

And you can search info about characters escaping here:
[String escape into XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132494/string-escape-into-xml])

or search in web "xml document escape special characters".

p.s.: your problem seems similiar to: [Special characters with XDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21488555/special-characters-with-xdocument)